# Confuse in choosing Big Database

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, php-mongodb

I am aware with mySql. But i am new with Big Database. Just i started RND on that. I have to use amazon webservices with BIG database.

Now my questions is that ..

**I am confuse with Big database selection which i have to use ? and why ?**

i have limited time to do RND on that. Just i have to make selection only.

I found that for BIG database mostly developer using **'dynamodb, nosql, mongodb, Hive, hadoop, etc... '**.

Comment: @KishanPatel I was trying to understand the context :) From your question you appear to be confused about [Big Data](http://www.technologytransfer.eu/article/98/2012/1/What_Is_Big_Data_and_Why_Do_We_Need_It_.html) and the [tools](http://www.infoworld.com/d/business-intelligence/7-top-tools-taming-big-data-191131) used to process it. Check the links, they might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519688/differences-between-nosql-databases (also see my answer there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you might have googled somewhat for Big Data.  Though there are many nosql databases, but explanation for all can't be covered here.
It's all up-to the requirement according to which Bigdatabase/Nosql databases we choose.

Please refer following links for understanding what NOSQL databases are and why should we use it.

http://www.couchbase.com/why-nosql/nosql-database
http://nosql.findthebest.com/
http://nosql-database.org/
http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

These link will definitely guide you..!!